# Downsize the [resize]

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request, retag-request

Let's talk about [resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/resize) (and its synonym, [resizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/resizing)) for a moment.

1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? And is it unambiguous?

It tells little of the specifics of the questions, and is imprecise at the same time.

> Issues relating to the resizing of controls, windows, forms or screens.

IMVHO, they are clearly [dependent](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/) tags.

2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

Resizing, as described in tag info - as a rule of thumb - yes. Still, the description does not encompass either the real-life usage of the tag or its default semantic meaning.

3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

Seldom, if ever. Without additional qualification, it is almost completely useless - we already have a bunch of `*(re)size*` tags, e.g. [image-size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/image-size), [image-resizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/image-resizing), [filesize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/filesize), [font-size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/font-size) etc. for that reason, (some of them being borderline burninable by themself).

4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

No. They can mean a lot of different things depending on context, and are actually umbrella terms to cover a wide range of partially overlapping concepts. Also, the description of [resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/resize) is IMVHO invalid - e.g. resizing an image or a disk partition should also be covered by [resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/resize), otherwise it's completely unintuitive to use.

The Ultimate Question:

> Is the tag causing a fairly large amount of harm?

IMVHO, yes, mainly due to their undying popularity. It prevents a noticeable amount of newbie people from properly tagging their questions with appropriate topic-related tags, making it harder for them to get answers, and for us to find them.

The solution here would be probably to retag some of those questions to proper qualified tags. I am aware that the amount of work is enormous here, though.

Comment: They're not meta-tags, they just don't describe much. A meta-tag doesn't have anything to do with the question itself (i.e. i'm a [beginner]).

Comment: @JL2210 IFTFY, I see that 'clearly' was a heavy overstatement here. Still, would a question tagged only [size] be tagged properly, would it be clear and understandable what particular technology does it concern? IMO, no. As such, the `If the tag can’t work as the only tag on a question, it’s probably a meta-tag.` + `If the tag commonly means different things to different people, it’s probably a meta-tag.` - for me, both of these apply here. Whether it's semantically a real "meta-tag" does not concern me (a real "metatag tag" would be a tag that tags a tag, by definition).

Comment: @ErikA true enough; I looked for dupe but couldn't find it, and posted two candidates because they were overlapping - but I completely agree, I've edited the request. OTOH, the original [size] request doesn't follow the new 'burninate procedure' at all, since it probably predates it by a couple of months/years.

Comment: Sadly, Shog wants us to do one post per tag. So, this post, while trying to touch other tags, isn't a duplicate of the [size] burnination.